# Efficiently detect changes in specific byte interval of file

Tags: java, shared-memory

I have to create a communication protocol that is based on a file (the file is memory-mapped, but we can abstract from that for now). The byte layout is fix. There are serveral areas, which have different functions.

There is a certain area for 'notifications', e. g. byte# 0 up to byte# 32k. Each byte has one of two values. Let's say **0x00** and **0xFF**. The indices have a semantic, so if **byte# 0** get's updated from 0x00 to 0xFF it means that the information associated with **key 0** got updated.
Interesting for me are all transitions from 0x00 to 0xFF and vice versa.

So my question is:

Is there an **efficient**, maybe native, **non-polling** approach to detect file changes (resp. the aforementioned transitions) in a certain area?

---

**Additional info**

Although I have specified java as language, I'm willing to accept solution in other languages that can be called via java (e.g. C++ via JNI).

It is a 1-to-n protocol, there is 1 main application, that communicates with up to n others. So checking the whole file for changes is not the optimum. I can't call it bad either, since the application is mostly used in a way that one could assume 1-to-1 at given a time, but that's not necessairly always the case.

I also am told to use only 1 file.

Comment: You will also need to decide whether you want it to be cross-platform.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a solution for specific areas in the file but you could listen to any file changes and then poll the specific bytes and check those.

Comment: @chiastic-security yes, you're are right. Actually it is cross-platform. But java is enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or at least, nearly: use `java.nio.file.WatchService` for this.

```
FileSystem filesystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
WatchService watcher = filesystem.newWatchService();
```

After this, you can register watch events using this watcher.

```
Path dir = fileSystem.getPath("/tmp/file");
dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKind.ENTRY_MODIFY);
```

This won't tell you whether that specific area of the file changed, but it will notify you when there is some kind of change. This is the best you'll get, I think.

If this isn't good enough, you could split the file into two pieces: a header (which you watch) and a body (which you don't).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I updated the additional info. The problem is watching the whole file is probably not good enough. Maintaining multiple files would be easier yes, but I have to use one. And I'm not sure, if I can bend that rule.